# am cmd in sh script file does not work

Tags: android

the sh file looks as follows

```
#!/system/bin/sh
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings
echo hello,world
exit 1
```

but it reports error like

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.Sett
}gs
Error type 3
} does not exist.lass {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings
hello,world
exit: Illegal number: 1
```

but when i type it in sh shell directly, like in adb shell prompt, type `am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings`, it works,and runs the activty

so, what's the problem?

Comment: uhm ever tried to set the `chmod +x` on your script?

Comment: btw,the android version is 2.3,and use sh hello.sh to run the scripts.

Comment: chmod 777 hello.sh is used, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your script and it worked obviously.
Used 2.3.3 as well

```
echo "#!/system/bin/sh" >a.sh
#echo "#!/system/bin/sh" >a.sh
#cat a.sh
#!/system/bin/sh
# echo "am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings" >>a.sh
echo "am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings" >>a.sh
# cat a.sh
cat a.sh
#!/system/bin/sh
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings
# echo "echo hello, world" >>a.sh
echo "echo hello, world" >>a.sh
# echo "exit 0" >>a.sh
echo "exit 0" >>a.sh
# cat a.sh
cat a.sh
#!/system/bin/sh
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings
echo hello, world
exit 0   
# chmod 755 a.sh
chmod 755 a.sh
# ./a.sh
./a.sh
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings }
hello, world  
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
BogoMIPS        : 287.53
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0x926
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : Goldfish
```

Comment: but in my case, i adb push a.sh to my device. then chmod and run. it still does't work. you may have a try and hack why.

Comment: and in this case, you can't run the scripts by ./a.sh, and use sh a.sh instead, and i don't know why. anyway.